# Why does dryness irritate mucosal surfaces, and what exactly is this "irritation"?

Tags: physiology

The mucosal surfaces of the body function to moisten the epithelial linings and keep them from becoming dry. Why is this important? As an example, the respiratory tract moistens and warms the air that we inhale before it gets to the lungs, to protect it from damage and "irritation". How would cold, dry air cause those things?

Comment: How do you think it would cause those things?

Comment: I genuinely have no idea, I sat down a few times and looked it up as much as I could, nothing really describes how dryness and coldness irritates a cellular lining.